# E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I use `sudo apt-get update` I get following error.

```
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,

```
$ sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Incase you get this error E: Lists directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing.**

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same problem exist.

Comment: what error are you getting